# Update task record after "mark as complete" on update message

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I need to update some fields and do some login on `task` entity.
Actually based on my requirement, when the task `record status` change to `complete`(user click on `Mark as Complete`.), my logic must start.
For this reason and because of no `event` like `complete` in `task messages`, I check status of the record in `update message`.
I would like to this via `CRM Plugin`.
To achieve this I use `PostEntityImages` of task record.
I check the status of `PostEntityImages` in the code and then do my logic.
This is what happening :

```
        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
            currentTask = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
            if (currentTask.LogicalName == "task")
            {
                afterUpdateTask = (Entity)context.PostEntityImages["updatedTask"];
                beforeUpdateTask = (Entity)context.PreEntityImages["updatedTask"];
                if (afterUpdateTask.Contains("statuscode"))
                {
                    int statuscode = ((OptionSetValue)afterUpdateTask["statuscode"]).Value;

                    if (statuscode == 5)
                    {
```

As you see I also get the `PreEntityImages` as well.
After last if, the logic starts and some fields update; the fields of `PostEntityImages`(afterUpdateTask ).
But `CRM` returns :

```
The object cannot be updated because it is read-only. If you contact support, please provide the technical details.
```

It seems CRM does not talk much off !
I also tried this with `PreEntityImages`(beforeUpdateTask), but it does not work for me.
Because it updates the fields in `task entity`, but does not change the status of record to `complete`, however in my scenario I need the `modifiedon` and `statuscode` fields of PostEntityImages.
Also tried with `currentTask` that is `(Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"]`, but it just change the `stauts` of record to `complete` without running my logic.

What should I do to update a task record after it change to complete?
Is it possible to do this via Plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activity entities in Dynamics 365 after being completed they become read only.

I would register the Plug-in in PreOperation on Update message, having StatusCode as filtering attribute and perform the logic there:

- Compare PreImage with Status Code in Plugin Execution Context and see if the status was changed to completed
- Loggin
- Changes to the Task Entity

Else, CRM will not allow the modification of a completed activity.

Comment: You are right, I did it on PreOperation stage.
I did update on PreImage, but how? I check the status of the PreImage record with after completed record that is :
context.InputParameters["Target"] entity.
If my condition meet, the logic execute on PreImage record.
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no message to catch Mark as Complete but yes you are right, you need update message to catch this event.
2. you can add filtering attribute(statuscode) to your update message, so that your plugin will not trigger for every other field update but only when you statuscode field is changed.
3. I think you want to update your task record when mark as complete i.e statuscode is sucess or something, Then you need to run your plugin as Postoperation stage.
4. Then you need to create Task entity object and add field with value to this object and perfrom service.update(TaskObject);

In addition, I do not see from your code which field are you trying to update? for example, you cannot update/change createdon,modifiedon and some read only fields.

If you wish to change the status of Task, you will have to update/chnage statuscode and statecode together.

Comment: From your points : I think I already have done your points number 1,2.
For point 3 you are right and I run this plugin in Postoperation stage; actually I update the PostEntityImages(afterUpdateTask ) in Postoperation stage.
I did not get your number 4.You mean I create new task record with my key/values?
before service.update(task) I assign values to the fields that are not readonly, they are custom values.
Could you explain more?